# Masonry with asynchronous picture loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, playframework, masonry

I am trying to show pictures next to each other with masonry. The problem is that masonry executes it's code before all the pictures are loaded in. Resulting in overlapping pictures: 
[image]

And I need something like this (this is when I resize the window after the pictures are loaded in:
[image]

Does somebody know how to fix this? I tried to use the `onresize()` method but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mahi I don't understand it. Can you explain it a bit more detailed?

Comment: reinit masonry after window load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the " imagesLoaded " Method, see [Masonry imagesloaded](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded)

Here is an example

```
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
   // init Masonry after all images have loaded
   $grid.masonry({
       // options...
   });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work the first time but I found out that you need to add `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>` it seperately.